# CamTwist + Blackmagic Intensity Thunderbolt Shuttle Settings

Tags: streaming, camcorder

I'm trying to set up CamTwist + a Blackmagic Intensity Thunderbolt Shuttle on a MacBook Pro but am getting a black screen in CamTwist.

What are the correct settings?

Thanks!

Comment: SOLVED: 

Mac System Preferences > Blackmagic Design > Set default video standard as > HD 1080i 59.94

CamTwist > Blackmagic HD 1080i 59.94 - 8 Bit

I figured out my camera settings using the Blackmagic Media Express app, which did detect the camera. Just take a look in the app's settings to find your camera's connection settings.

Comment: Hi Craig, and welcome to AVP!  I'm glad you found an answer to your question.  I realize that there is a waiting period to "answer" your own question, but now that that has passed, it would be great to have your answer as an "answer" so that future visitors can see that there is one.  Thanks, and once again, welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem...

Go to: Mac System Preferences > Blackmagic Design

Set default video standard as `HD 1080i 59.94 CamTwist` > `Blackmagic HD 1080i 59.94 - 8 Bit`

I figured out my camera settings using the Blackmagic Media Express app, which did detect the camera. Just take a look in the app's settings to find your camera's connection settings.

Comment: I can't seem to get my Blackmagic Intensity Shuttle Thunderbolt to show up in CamTwist under Video Devices - is there anything else you can think of that I might be missing? Usually the `HD 1080i 50` setting works for me, and